# distribution.dbo.MSdistribution_history comments explanation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, transactional-replication

The comment column of distributor.dbo.MSdistribution_history contains comments such as

```
<stats state="2" fetch="11554" wait="214007" cmds="17898546" callstogetreplcmds="106880">
    <sincelaststats elapsedtime="300" fetch="8" wait="291" cmds="1948689" cmdspersec="6495.000000" />
</stats>
```

The state value translates to

```
STATE   Indication
1       Normal Log
2       Reader Thread has to WAIT for Writer
3       Writer Thread has to WAIT for Reader
```

Is the comment telling me that the reader thread is waiting for the writer thread but has read 1948689 cmds since the last stats entry. Or is it telling me that the reader thread is waiting for the writer thread and the writer thread has written 1948689 cmds since the last stats entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/0b8bac44-da87-4115-90f6-b8bf1e1d0bd8

Both cmd values relate to the number of commands written. Since last stats - cmds are all cmds written since the last entry and stats- cmd are an accumulation of all cmds written since the last comment with a state of 1.